# Drupal 7 How to override page.tpl for specific content type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I wanted to override page.tpl.php for specific content type.
I have tried these thing, nothing works for me.

1. `page--article.tpl.php`
2. `page--node--article.tpl.php`
3. `page--node--type--article.tpl.php`
4. `page--node-type--article.tpl.php`
5. `page--type--article.tpl.php`

But when I targetted specific node by number i.e. `page--node--8.tpl.php` it worked fine.
I think `page--article.tpl.php` should have worked, but I dont know why its not working.

Please tell me if I am naming it wrong. and how can I debug such things. I have heard I can use Devel module, but know nothing about it. A slight hint in right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to make sure that your template can handle this ... I got a code snippet that worked for me here:

http://drupal.org/node/1089656#comment-4426790

```
<?php
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    // If the node type is "blog_madness" the template suggestion will be "page--blog-madness.tpl.php".
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you remembered to clear the cache (under Administer > Site configuration > Performance) so that Drupal is 'aware' of your new file & uses this rather than the default.

See here on [Clearing cached data](http://drupal.org/node/173880#theme-registry)

Also, you may need to add a preprocess hook (I haven't used D7 myself, just 5/6 — think this has changed slightly.) [This post on Drupal Stack Exchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/1512) seems to give more details

Comment: Drupal code theme suggestions does not have a node type template suggestions. So you must add a theme suggestion function to your template.php (See the above link) :)

Comment: You need to overwrite the node template file specific if its not a basic page.  No need to do the suggestion in the template.php if you are overriding the entire node

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem.

#### node--recipe.tpl.php

***not***

page--recipe.tpl.php

this is, of course, with a content type called 'recipe'.

Answer (score 1):

ALWAYS CLEAR THE CACHE...

Go to /admin/config/development/performance and click the clear cache button. It should be the first thing you do if you've made alterations to the structure of the backend and they're not showing as expected.

Otherwise you almost had it right

1. page--content-type-name.tpl.php

will allow you to theme the content type template.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if others arrive here, the way I override content types in drupal 7 is like this

node--*contenttype*.tpl

Answer (score 0):

You will need to overwrite the specific node template for the content type if it is anything different than a Basic Page.  Please check this out:

http://api.drupal.org/node/19080

Under this page copy/paste the items that are in the node.tpl.php page and overwrite it on how you want.  You can access the node specifically by $node

Your template for articles would be:

node--article.tpl.php

Once this is created make sure you clear cache to ensure this works.

Answer (score 0):

So depending on what you are trying to accomplish, there might be some CSS tricks that could help you out.

For instance, to override any CSS rules for a specific node type just remember that your pages for that node type will have a body class of `"node-type-[TYPE]"` (ie: `.node-type-article`)

You can then override the CSS as follows:

```
body.node-type-article #selector {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.create a content type for example: my content type is "fullwidthpage"

Step 2. copy **page.tpl.php**  and rename  to  **page--fullwidthpage.tpl**  in template folder.

Step 3. Add this code to **template.php**

```
function <strong>YOUR_THEME_NAME_HERE</strong>_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
    // If the content type's machine name is "my_machine_name" the file
    // name will be "page--my-machine-name.tpl.php".
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

> Don't forgot to change **YOUR_THEME_NAME_HERE**