# custom page-xxxx.tpl.php doesnt works

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have page named page--news.tpl.php, which i created for my news page. But after i cleared my cache, page still not using, and drupal use the original page.tpl.php. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drupal 7 How to override page.tpl for specific content type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193910/drupal-7-how-to-override-page-tpl-for-specific-content-type)

Comment: You are putting this into a custom theme? If so, do you have page.tpl.php in the same folder as page-news.tpl.php?

Comment: yes. More then my page--front.tpl hooked with no problem, but the rest just still now hooking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate way of doing it, is through preprocess hook with few lines of code.
Here's how it goes

```
function <module_name>_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (isset($variables['node'])) {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$variables['node']->type;
    }
}
```

Suppose you have a node type as "news" then tpl should look like 'page--news.tpl.php' and above code will handle the rest.

Comment: ill check this way, should help